# Checkbox Label overlapping the checkbox - Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using bootstrap 3 & the issue is that label for the checkbox is overlapping the text. I have tried a few thing things but did not work, so if someone can help I will really appreciate it. This is what the code looks like, The class of the form is form-horizontal

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">I have read and agree with    privacy and disclosure policy.
    <input name="Terms" id="Terms" type="checkbox" ></label>
</div>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's supposed to be like this with Bootstrap, `<input>` first and text after. http://jsfiddle.net/sqax02ah/

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-inline no_indent">
        <input name="Terms" id="Terms" type="checkbox">
        I have read and agree with privacy and disclosure policy.
    </label>
</div>
```

You can follow other answers if you do need the checkbox appears at the end.

Comment: this is worked for me ... thank you .. how can i set style to my current class to apply this change. i have many input elements in my project, i want to change only my current class that applied and set to all my inputs in whole of my project, how can i implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap the styles expect thecheckbox to be first and then the text and hence a `margin-left: -20px` is set. For you snippet you need to add custom styles.

```
.radio input[type=radio], .radio-inline input[type=radio], .checkbox input[type=checkbox], .checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-right: -20px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5q8thwf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try use `display: inline-block` for .checkbox class, its should to help. Or change position via margin `margin-left: 20px;`